# Script for Generate Databases in Powershell

Tags: sqlite, powershell

The Script below generated my databases

```
foreach ($dir in (Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\Year_2015')) {
  Clear-Host;
  Push-Location $dir.FullName;
  C:\Teste\Teste2\file.bat $dir.FullName;
  Pop-Location;
  Clear-Host
}
```

By Duncan.

The code of `file.bat`:

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~1\QGISVA~1
SET PYTHONPATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGISVA~1\apps\qgis\python;
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
rem call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\env.bat
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;
rem #---[Dispara Carga_DB.py]
call python C:\\Teste\\Test2\\Pypgr\\Carga_db.py
PAUSE
```

The script generated databases. I would like to know the following: The script generates the database in the following folders:

```
C:\Year_2015\folder_1\Data\a.db
c:\Year_2015\folder_2\Data\b.db
c:\Year_2015\folder_3\Data\c.db
```

etc .... Let's assume that I sent generate these first three banks. Tomorrow, I go back to work and need to generate banks:

```
c:\Year_2015\folder_4\Data\d.db
c:\Year_2015\folder_5\Data\e.db
```

However, when you run the script to generate that two new banks, he is doing a reading in every other again, or trying to generate those already generated! How do I make the script run just to generate the new banks?

Comment: Why does your PowerShell script call a batch script that calls a Python script to create an SQLite database? Also, you need to show the Python code, since that script apparently is the one actually creating the databases.

Answer (score 0):

This will filter out any folders that have a *.db file in them somewhere.  Without more knowledge of the logic of your Python script, it's not really possible to be more accurate.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\Year_2015' | Where-Object {
    (Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.db').Count -eq 0
} | ForEach-Object {
    Clear-Host; 
    Push-Location $_.FullName; 
    C:\Teste\Teste2\file.bat $_.FullName; 
    Pop-Location; 
    Clear-Host;
}
```